# Use WP_Theme::scandir function to scan a plugin directory. Is there a way?

Tags: plugin-development, directory

I'd like to scan a plugin's directory for files with specific extensions, like php, css and js.

I know there is `scandir()` function in `WP_Theme` class that's perfect for this work. The problem is that it's declared `private` so I can't use it outside of the class.

Any advice what's the best way to do this? Is there another native WP function that can be used instead?

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: how about… [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: @Milo, I couldn't figure out how to use specific file extensions with PHP's scandir. Is it possible?

Comment: check the returned array for specific file types, or use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with a pattern.

Comment: Just looking into glob function.. I don't think it scans the nested folders. I'm more tempted to copy over the `WP_Theme::scandir()` function. Unless, there is some other similar function that WP provides, that does most of the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the inputs and advice.

I've decided to copy over the `WP_Theme::scandir()` function itself. I understand what's going on there and there is no other native WP function to scan directories for files with specific extensions (with an option scanning sub-folders).

P.S. I could not figure out how to link to WP code. Here is the copy of the `WP_Theme::scandir()` as of 13 Jan 2014

```
/**
 * Scans a directory for files of a certain extension.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param string $path Absolute path to search.
 * @param mixed  Array of extensions to find, string of a single extension, or null for all extensions.
 * @param int $depth How deep to search for files. Optional, defaults to a flat scan (0 depth). -1 depth is infinite.
 * @param string $relative_path The basename of the absolute path. Used to control the returned path
 *  for the found files, particularly when this function recurses to lower depths.
 */
private static function scandir( $path, $extensions = null, $depth = 0, $relative_path = '' ) {
    if ( ! is_dir( $path ) )
        return false;

    if ( $extensions ) {
        $extensions = (array) $extensions;
        $_extensions = implode( '|', $extensions );
    }

    $relative_path = trailingslashit( $relative_path );
    if ( '/' == $relative_path )
        $relative_path = '';

    $results = scandir( $path );
    $files = array();

    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        if ( '.' == $result[0] )
            continue;
        if ( is_dir( $path . '/' . $result ) ) {
            if ( ! $depth || 'CVS' == $result )
                continue;
            $found = self::scandir( $path . '/' . $result, $extensions, $depth - 1 , $relative_path . $result );
            $files = array_merge_recursive( $files, $found );
        } elseif ( ! $extensions || preg_match( '~\.(' . $_extensions . ')$~', $result ) ) {
            $files[ $relative_path . $result ] = $path . '/' . $result;
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: It is not easier to scan via `glob`, like `$files = glob( "folder_path/*.php" );`?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? didn't it help?

Comment: @RahilWazir, thank you for taking time and helping. The only reason I went for WP function is because it's already exists with all the functionality that I wanted (specific extensions, sub-folder lookup). And I understand what's going on there a bit more.

Comment: Rahils answer uses a recursive directory iterator, aka it recurses down through the folders into sub and sub sub and sub sub sub folders etc. It does everything you need it to do, and perhaps it may even be faster ( its certainly simpler ), for that it deserves an up vote at least

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP5 [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) with [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
$directory = '/project_root/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin'; //Your plugin dir

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

    while ($it->valid()) { //Check the file exist
    if (!$it->isDot()) { //if not parent ".." or current "."
            if (strpos($it->key(), '.php') !== false
               || strpos($it->key(), '.css') !== false
               || strpos($it->key(), '.js') !== false
            ) {
                //Do your stuff with matched extension files
                echo $it->key() . '<br>'; //output: main.js, index.php, style.css etc....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of WP 3.4 there is a public `get_files()` method. You can create a `WP_Theme` instance with the plugin dir set as theme root.

```
// get theme instance of WP_Theme
$current_dir = new WP_Theme('my-plugin-dir',WP_PLUGIN_DIR);

// get js and css files up to 10 subfolders depth
$files = $current_dir->get_files( array('js','css') , 10 );
```

There isn't very much documentation on it in the [WP-Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme#Files_and_Images), so having a look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L918) might be more instructive.